# android app crashes if keyboard was shown

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that I force keyboard to appears using,

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

keyboard appears properly and also obscured when needed. Problem is when I finish the activity, app crashes.
If the activity never shows keyboard or shows it without start editing text, it is finished with no errors but if you just write one single character or more, app will crash. How to solve it? thank you.

method used to finish activity,

```
    boto_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);


                    finish();
                }
            });
 @Override
      public void onDestroy() 
      {
        if (adMob != null) 
        {
          // Destroy the AdView.
          adMob.destroy();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
      }
```

logcat,

```
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxxx.projecte1.TabBar_iOSActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxxx.projecte1.webPush}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2711)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:121)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:976)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxxx.projecte1.webPush}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchDestroy(LocalActivityManager.java:622)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.onDestroy(ActivityGroup.java:85)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at com.xxxx.projecte1.TabBar_iOSActivity.onDestroy(TabBar_iOSActivity.java:417)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2680)
07-07 19:04:25.191: E/AndroidRuntime(8443):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Observing the exception in LogCat could lead you closer to the answer.

Comment: Please paste your code and log, so a precise decision can be made abt the crash

Comment: posted, hope could help!

Comment: Can you post your onDestroy method please?

Comment: The problem is in file TabBar_iOSActivity.java line 417. Some object is equal to null there

Comment: @Jaume : I have encountered the same problem but could not find a solution. When I inspected logcat, I found out that it is due to a null pointer exception. And it occured in the line.- inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); But inputMethodManager was not null at all. This only occured when I did this multiple times(that is in different onClickListeners) . Is this the only place where you are using inputMethodManager in this activity?

Comment: yes, is the only place. When activity finishes without crashing (keyboard was not popped or edit did not start), keyboars appears and dissapears. I don't know if this can be a clue.

Comment: remove initialization of InputMethod's line in onclick.
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

Comment: Try using Application context to get the `InputMethodManager`: `getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)`;

Comment: There is no need to Hide keyboard when you are finishing activity, because if InputMethod is started by the activity, then it will be removed first and then activity window. Can you please verify this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this way:

**For showing keyboard:**

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(inputEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

**For Hiding:**

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: thanks but this part is already supported. Problem is that qhen I finish activity and keybord was shown, app crashes

Comment: @Jaume, I read somewhere that toggleSoftInput causes some problems. So I thought you should give this a try.

Comment: @Jaume could you please post your project somewhere, I could not reproduce the problem. I am really interested to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Is this your only activity.............??

**If yes......Try by removing the finish();**

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the flags reversed:

From Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#toggleSoftInput%28int,%20int%29), the `toggleSoftInput` function has the following parameters:

```
public void toggleSoftInput (int showFlags, int hideFlags)
```

while in your usage, you are using the hideFlags in place of the showFlags:

```
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Try swapping them as below:

```
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you can always catch the exception with a try catch block like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() 
  {
    try {
       if (adMob != null) 
       {
         // Destroy the AdView.
         adMob.destroy();
       }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //Or don't print it if you dont want.
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

Although, this is not the best approach (maybe the least preferable) but it gets the job done. Since you are exiting the activty, i don't believe that this would mess something up.